# WatchKit start with different controllers?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I'm designing my first Apple Watch app. I'd like the first scene displayed on the Apple Watch to be different depending on information in the iOS app. Can I call pushcontrollerwithname or presentControllerWithName inside the initial WatchKit controller's awakeWithContext once I determine the right controller to display? Will the user notice a delay or transition? Is there a better way do do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, one of our apps does this and is live in the app store.

Comment: Thanks. Does the user only see the target scene without a delay or (worse) transition to it?

Comment: It will depend on what code you need to execute and where you place it. Just do a few test to see what works best for your app.